# Recursively deleting folder in CodeIgniter FTP Class

Tags: php, codeigniter, ftp

I am using the CI FTP class, with the function delete_dir, its supposed to delete the folder and everything side of it, however, if the folder has files in it, it won't delete the folder and outputs an error.

The function is as follows;

```
function delete_dir($filepath)
{
    if ( ! $this->_is_conn())
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Add a trailing slash to the file path if needed
    $filepath = preg_replace("/(.+?)\/*$/", "\\1/",  $filepath);

    $list = $this->list_files($filepath);

    if ($list !== FALSE AND count($list) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($list as $item)
        {
            // If we can't delete the item it's probaly a folder so
            // we'll recursively call delete_dir()
            if ( ! @ftp_delete($this->conn_id, $item))
            {
                $this->delete_dir($item);
            }
        }
    }
```

Anyone know of any bugs?

Comment: In all likelihood, `ftp_delete` is throwing an error (e.g. permission denied), which is being suppressed by the `@`. Remove the `@` sign to see the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ftp_delete` is most likely throwing an error that is not related to deleting a directory (e.g. a permissions issue). To show the error, remove the `@` before `ftp_delete`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can delete the contents and the folder with an FTP client, then you should be able to delete the same with the code as well. Try modifying the the function like the one shown below

```
function delete_dir($filepath)
{
    if ( ! $this->_is_conn())
    {
        return FALSE;
    }

    // Add a trailing slash to the file path if needed
    $filepath = preg_replace("/(.+?)\/*$/", "\\1/",  $filepath);

    $list = $this->list_files($filepath);

    if ($list !== FALSE AND count($list) > 0)
    {
        foreach ($list as $item)
        {
            // If we can't delete the item it's probaly a folder so
            // we'll recursively call delete_dir()
            if ( ! @ftp_delete($this->conn_id, $filepath.$item))
            {
                $this->delete_dir($filepath.$item);
            }
        }
    }

    $result = @ftp_rmdir($this->conn_id, $filepath);

    if ($result === FALSE)
    {
        if ($this->debug == TRUE)
        {
            $this->_error('ftp_unable_to_delete');
        }
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```